# Smarty form validation using PHP

Tags: php, validation, smarty3

I want to validate my form using PHP on Smarty template. I have searched in the web and here for some solutions, but nothing work in my case. I want to stay on the same page if some field is empty or filled with incorrect data. The file "result.php" is the page where the correct submited data goes to. I have done it, using **javascript**, but i want to know how to do it with **PHP** in case of disabled javascript in the user browser and for more complex check run (white spaces, empty fields, incorrect characters...). The posted PHP script does not do any validation and i get an undefined index: error. I post a piece of my code. Please, help. Thanks in advance!

**php code (index.php):**

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
if (!empty($scrubbed['name']) || !empty($scrubbed['age'])) {
    header("Location: result.php");
 }
else {
    $smarty->assign('error', 'Please fill out the form completely');
    $smarty->display('index.tpl');
 }
}
```

**smarty code (index.tpl):**

```
{$error}
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="5">
<form name="infoform" action="result.php" method="post">  
<tr>
    <td><div align="right">Name:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" size="20"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><div align="right">Age:</div></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="age" size="2" min="1" max="65"/></td>
</tr>
...
```

Comment: Do you get this error only when you open the form without posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**php code (index.php):**

Instead redirect just do validation here:

```
if (!empty($scrubbed['name']) || !empty($scrubbed['age'])) {
    // do something with post data, validate it
}
```

**smarty code (index.tpl):**

To avoid message `undefined index: error` just do:

```
{if isset($error)}

    {* do something here if You have error... *}

{/if}
```